# Why can't I set protections on /root/.gvfs?

Tags: bash, filesystems, file-permissions

My question is why can't I set permissions on a file in /root?

I'm stumped. This bash script run from cron as a non-root user

```
#!/bin/bash
# mail_df.sh Charles M. Norton 01/07/2013
# Emails df to some folks.

df | mail -s "Disk Usage For Public.somewhere.za.us" \
    french.toast@maplesyrup.com
```

just started throwing out this error `df: /root/.gvfs`: Permission denied`, after an upgrade to our Centos 6 list server.

OK, so I'm going to fix this by having this run as root out of cron, but for some reason I cannot set the permissions on .gvfs as root.

I tried this as a workaround. I cannot figure out why chmod 755 .gvfs does not work, when command is issued by root.

```
[root@public ~]# ls -lda .gvfs
dr-x------. 2 root root 0 Feb 23 10:53 .gvfs
```

[root@public ~]#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any user that tries to modify the permissions of the files and directories inside `/root` needs execution permissions for `/root` itself. Since the same happened to `.gvfs`, I suspect that the permissions of `/root` got somehow altered as well.

Try executing this as root:

```
chmod 700 /root
chmod 755 /root/.gvfs
```